# Flux<DataBuffer> to Outputstream

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, download, spring-webflux

I am downloading a file from a REST api and want to pass it on to my Angular application. So a download function.
Currently the downloaded file is written to a file using DataBufferUtils and then the file is given to the output stream of the response.

But now I want the data from the Flux to go directly into the output stream and not be cached.

The following implementation had the problem that the desired ZIP folder is downloaded but unfortunately empty

```
  public Flux<DataBuffer> downloadFiles( OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,String id) {
        return get(uri).attributes(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                .retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
    }
```

```
  dataBufferFlux = orderWebService.downloadFiles(authorizedClient,id);
  DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux,response.getOutputStream());
```

Angular:

```
return this.http.get(uri, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
      withCredentials: true
    })
      .pipe(map(res => {
          const contentDisposition = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
          const filename = this.getFilenameFromContentDisposition(contentDisposition);

          return {
            body: new Blob([res.body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')}),
            filename: filename
          }
        })
      ).subscribe(response => {

      let binaryData = [];
      binaryData.push(response.body);
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/pdf"}));
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
      a.setAttribute('target', 'blank');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = response.filename;
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      a.remove();

    }, error => {

      console.log(error);
    });
```

I am grateful for any help and inspiration!

Comment: Hint: what does `DataBufferUtils.write` return? What does a `Flux` do if you don’t subscribe to it? It might helpful to read the docs of the method you’re using - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#write-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.io.OutputStream-

Comment: @BoristheSpider thank you for the comment. I added subscribe()  but unfortunately still the same problem.

After the download of the Rest API was successful I get the following error message:
org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Failed write
I guess that the output stream is already closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution above caused out of memory issues for me, but I came up with this looking at the code of `DataBufferUtils` which works just fine:

```
    StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream -> Mono.create(sink ->
        DataBufferUtils.write(myFlux, outputStream).subscribe(DataBufferUtils::release,
            sink::error,
            sink::success))
        .block();
```

My lack of experience with Webflux/RxJava prevents me offering any explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

First I'm getting the `Flux<DataBuffer>`:

```
return webClient
        .get()
        .uri(url)
        .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId(CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
```

Once you have that, and assuming that you also have the `HttpServletResponse response` in your controller, you can do this:

```
try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="file.pdf");
    DataBufferUtils.write(flux, outputStream).share().blockLast();
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error writing to response", e);
}
```

The javadoc of the write says:

> ... Does **not** close the output stream when the flux is terminated, and does **not** release the data buffers in the source

The try-with-resources should have you covered closing the output stream and the combination of `share().blockLast()` I think it's enough for the data buffer.

Please notice that given that `blockLast` is invoked, this is now a blocking operation

Comment: Why is `share()` necessary?

Comment: Warning: This will cause resource leaks; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With little modifications to the above answer, the following code worked for me

```
final Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux =
      webClient
          .get()
          .uri(uri)
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
// Write to http response outputstream directly. Block only for an hour.
DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux, httpResponse.getOutputStream()).blockLast(Duration.ofSeconds(3600));
```

Comment: Warning: This will cause resource leaks; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most simple solution:

```
DataBufferUtils
    .write(flux, target)
    .map {
        DataBufferUtils.release(it)
    }
    .blockLast(downloadTimeout)
```

Explanation: `DataBufferUtils.write(Flux, OutputStream)` will set up everything to copy the stream of `DataBuffer`s into the `OutputStream` and then return immediately without actually starting the work.

You have now two problems to solve:

1. Make sure the resources related to the `DataBuffer` are released ([see the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#write(org.reactivestreams.Publisher,java.io.OutputStream)))
2. Block until the operation is finished.

The logic of `Flux` dictates that all operations happen in the order in which they were set up. Internally, `write()` will do some magic so you get something like this:

```
DataBufferUtils
    .map { it ->
        ... copy databuffer to stream ...
    }
    .map { it ->
        DataBufferUtils.release(it)
    }
```

so the `map()` operation to release the resources will happen after the data has been processed.

The last bit is to block until the `Flux` runs out of `DataBuffer`s to process.

Note: This second step is only necessary in unit tests and similar code where you need to make sure the operation has finished. If you execute this code in a controller, you can just return the flux (after the call to `map()` which releases the buffers) and Spring will make sure the whole operation happens eventually.