# Understanding DataBufferUtils.write to OutputStream

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm downloading huge documents from internal servers in a kind of proxy. In a nutshell, I have a `Flux<DataBuffer>` and an `OutputStream`. So I thought I could use

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils#write(
    org.reactivestreams.Publisher<org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer>,
    java.io.OutputStream
)
```

but that returns a Flux and I'm not sure what to do with it.

`Flux.blockFirst()` will just process the start of the file.

`Flux.blockLast()` logs thousands of resource leaks. I think that makes sense because the specific `write()` method clearly states that the caller is responsible for releasing the `DataBuffer`s.

`Flux.subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())` doesn't do anything when I run the code from a unit test. My guess is that the VM terminates before Spring has a chance to start the processing.

The code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75295377/34088) works but I don't understand why:

```
Mono.create(sink ->
    DataBufferUtils
        .write(myFlux, outputStream)
        .subscribe(
            DataBufferUtils::release,
            sink::error,
            sink::success
        )
)
    .block()
```

Why does this download the document without resource leaks? How does wrapping the `Flux` in a `Mono` make a difference?

Comment: What's full code for `Flux.subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())` attempt?

Comment: You do not  need to wrap Flux returned by `DataBufferUtils.write`. It is not doing anything to make this code work. All you need to do is close source resource after writing to outputstream. Flux returned by write simply return the source DataBuffer.So, `DataBufferUtils.write(myFlux, outputStream)
                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())` will work and is same as `DataBufferUtils.write(getRead(), fStream)
                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils::release)`

Comment: The only thing wrapping does, is blocking until flux is written. So it's rather the same as `DataBufferUtils.write(myFlux, outputStream).doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release).blockLast()`

Comment: @gdomo 1. Why does subscribing error and success block until the flux is written? How does that connect the Mono to the Flux in a meaningful way?
2. what is the difference between `.doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release).blockLast()` and `.map(DataBufferUtils::release).blockLast() `?

Comment: 1. Blocking until Flux is written is archived by combination of: a) `.block()` on a Mono (manually created). It's the exactly where blocking happens 2) finishing eventually that Mono by calling `sink::success`/`sink::error` when original Flux is finished. Here `sink` is the Mono's sink. And to make success/error called you pass references to that methods to Flux's `subscribe`. Reactor calls them when Flux is finished.

Comment: 2) `.map(DataBufferUtils::release)` does realising (side effect) and turns your `Flux<DataBuffer>` to `Flux<Boolean>`, since `release` returns boolean. `doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release).` keeps Flux as is, just adds a side effect. Since you do no need actual last Flux value, both approaches is suitable for you

Comment: @gdomo This is the answer I'm looking for. Please copy the comments into an answer and add: Who releases the last DataBuffer when I use `doOnNext()`?

Comment: `DataBufferUtils.release()` will be executed on each DataBuffer including the last one. Btw, have you tried `DataBufferUtils.write(myFlux, outputStream).doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release).blockLast()` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That piece of code is capable of writing given Flux and releasing resources:

```
DataBufferUtils
        .write(myFlux, outputStream)
        .subscribe(
            DataBufferUtils::release,
```

`write(myFlux, outputStream)` do the writing and `DataBufferUtils::release` is provided as a subscribe's first argument, which is a function that reactor will call on each buffer. So that's how you avoid memory leak.

Rest of code including wrapping to Mono is just an approach to block until your flux is finished, i.e. written:

```
Mono.create(sink ->
    // ...
            sink::error,
            sink::success
        )
)
    .block()
```

`sink::error` and `sink::success` is 2nd and 3rd arguments of `subscribe` which are functions that reactor will call when original Flux is finished (normally or exceptionally), i.e. written. Since `sink` here is `Mono`'s sink calling them finishes the manually created Mono. That's how you turn a Flux to a Mono, which is completed when the Flux is completed.

Finally, calling `.block` on that Mono blocks a thread until Mono's (and hence the original Flux) is finished. That is were the actual block happens.

I expect here is a simpler solution:

```
DataBufferUtils.write(myFlux, outputStream).doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release).blockLast()
```

You don't actually need extra Mono, all you need is to call `DataBufferUtils::release` on each buffer after is was written and block until end of Flux, i.e. `blockLast`. You can replace `doOnNext` (adds a side-effect) with `map` (converts items with a possible side-effect), what will turn `Flux<DataBuffer>` to a `Flux<Boolean>`, since release returns boolean. Inasmuch as you don't use neither buffer's nor booleans and just block until the end, both methods are suitable for you here.